# How to create a method that compares an unknown number of strings in C++?

Tags: c++, compare, parameter-passing, infinite

After some research I found that in C++ I can create a function with infinite variables in this way:

```cpp
template<typename ... Args>
void func(Args... a) {
    /* CODE */
}
```

I want to make a method that compares an unknown number of strings and gives a bool: true if are equal and false if are not equal.

I did something like this but I don't know how to iterate the strings.

```cpp
template<typename ... Strings>
bool cmp(string first, Strings... rest) {
    /* ITERATE AND COMPARE */

    return false;
}
```

So how I can iterate them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term *infinite variables* is not correct. C++ can handle variable numbers of function arguments but not infinitely many ones.

If you can use C++17 a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) would be the easiest solution:

```
template<typename ... Ts>
bool cmp(const std::string& first, const std::string& second, const Ts&... rest) {
    return (cmp(second, rest) && ... && (second == first));
}
```

Again using C++17 you can also use a recursive approach using `if constepxr`:

```
template<typename ... Ts>
bool cmp(const std::string& first, const std::string& second, const Ts&... rest) {
    if constexpr (!sizeof...(Ts)) {  // Do we have only two arguments left?
        return first == second;
    } else {
        return first == second && cmp(second, rest...);
    }
}
```

For C++14 you can simply overload the two argument version and use again recursion:

```
bool cmp(const std::string& first, const std::string& second) {
    return first == second;
}

template<typename ... Ts>
bool cmp(const std::string& first, const std::string& second, const Ts&... rest) {
    return first == second && cmp(second, rest...);
}
```

Comment: You can just overload `cmp` with a non-template two arg version. The non-template version will be called in preference to the template version. Then you don't need `if consexpr`

Comment: If you change the recursion to `first == second && cmp(rest...)` then you get two advantages: the comparison will stop as soon as two strings don't match, and the compiler can optimize the tail recursion.

Comment: Also you made a mistake in the recursive call, it should be `cmp(second, rest, ...)`

Comment: Also, this doesn't do what the original question asks for, which is to return true if all strings are equal. Your example function returns true if the strings are pairwise equal.

Comment: Thanks @john, this fixes also the pair-wise problem.